# How can I syntax check a Scala script without executing the script and generating any class files?

Tags: scala, scripting

One can write scripts in Scala. So you can put this into Hello.scala

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala $0 $@
!#

println("You supplied " + args.length + " arguments!")
```

and make it executable in Unix by

```
chmod u+x Hello.scala
```

Then you can run the script simply by

```
./Hello.scala
```

This compiles the script and runs it if there are no syntax errors. However, this does not account for situation when I only want to syntax check **without** executing the script. I do not want to modify the script (i.e. by removing the #! directive) and I do not want any *.class files to be generated.

How can I syntax check a Scala script?

Comment: Checking syntax only is probably easiest done by creating a basic parser with tools like ANTLR using the grammar given in language spec. Do you want to perform name and type checking, too? If so, things get messy and you probably want to work with (parts of) scalac directly.

Comment: I was not precise in my question. I want to perform syntax checking as well as type checking and I want to use Scala compiler / infrastructure. Miles' answer below is right on the button.

Comment: Supposedly scalacheck provides a command-line syntax checker https://scalacheck.org/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I expect that you actually want a little more than just checking for correct syntax ... presumably what you want to know is that your file would compile correctly if you did  actually compile it. That involves type checking as well as syntax checking.

For Scala source files (ie. not scripts) you can specify the -Ystop:refchecks command line argument to cause the compiler to stop before it starts code generation (if you really are only interested in syntactic correctness you could specify -Ystop:parser). If there are errors they will be shown on the console in exactly the same way as if you fully compiled the sources.

For Scala scripts you can also specify the -Ystop:refchecks argument. If you do this, then you will either see compile errors reported on the console or, if there are no errors in the script, you will see the following,

```
$ scala -Ystop:refchecks Hello.scala 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

The ClassNotFoundException indicating that no classfiles have been generated and that your script has not been executed.

Comment: Excellent answer. Your interpretation is correct. I want to know if the file would compile correctly if I actually did compile it. Thanks.

Comment: Is this still valid?  Doesn't seem to work with scala 2.9.  Can't find any info on this in a search.  Thanks.

Comment: With scalac in 2.9 try the option -Ystop-after:refchecks instead of -Ystop:refchecks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut lines off your file to pass to the interpreter, you can create a script called `CutScala.scala` (or whatever you prefer):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala $0 $@
!#

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.io._

val p = new ProcessBuilder(
  List(
    "scala",
    "-e",
    io.Source.fromFile(args(1)).getLines().drop(args(0).toInt).mkString("\n")
  ) :::
  args.drop(2).toList
).start()

p.waitFor

val output = List(p.getInputStream,p.getErrorStream).map(
  x => new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(x))
)

println("Exit code = " + p.exitValue)
for ((reader,title) <- (output zip List("Output:","Errors:"))) {
  println(title);
  Iterator.continually(reader.readLine).takeWhile(_!=null).foreach(println)
  println
}
```

and then call it like

```
./CutScala.scala 4 Hello.scala a b c
```

to drop the first 4 lines and just parse the rest.  Miles' answer tells you how to do the other (more difficult) half of not producing any output and not running anything.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich - Or `tail -n+4`.  The problem is that AFAICT the Scala script interpreter won't take stdin, and that you cannot robustly avoid tokenizing a command replacement, so that relatively trivial attempts to stuff the text into `-e` don't work.

Comment: `cat $1|awk 'NR >4' >/tmp/tmp.$1 && scalac /tmp/tmp.$1 ; rm /tmp/tmp.$1` or a little bit more sophisticated way to generate unique file name for the sake of completeness. But so much code for a trivial tasks proves to me that this is the wrong tool for the job. Also consider that you have to suffer the JVM startup times twice, for the script and for `scala`.

Comment: @Elazar - I assumed that since the OP wanted zero class files generated (instead of generating them in a temp dir and deleting them) that he also wanted no other temp files generated.  It's obviously easy to do with temp files.  But anyway, agreed, perl or awk or somesuch is better for quick one-liners.  For me, the crossover point where Scala becomes easier usually happens at 5-10 lines.