# Is it possible for Scala to offer type checking inside scripts?

Tags: scala, scripting

Does anyone know if there's a way to do have type checking in scripts for Scala? When I'm writing short scripts, I feel I lose a lot of the strength of Scala's typechecking (i.e. catching errors when writing code, rather than when I try and compile).

Comment: You probably mean on the fly syntax checking rather than type checking. Script or not, Scala is statically typed.

Comment: This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204864/how-can-i-syntax-check-a-scala-script-without-executing-the-script-and-generating

Answer (score 0):

See this fantastic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204864/how-can-i-syntax-check-a-scala-script-without-executing-the-script-and-generatin/5205677#5205677) by Miles Sabin; thanks to tenshi for pointing this out.  You want to run

```
scala -Ystop:refchecks ScriptToCheck.scala
```

Success is indicated by this output:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

I agree that it would be nice if a more user-friendly way were available (the `-Y` compiler options are quite arcane, and subject to change without notice; the success message belies the "hackishness" of this solution).  But for the time being, you should be able to use this.

Hope I've been helpful.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the Ecplise Scala IDE it supports incremental compilation, just like the JDT does for Java. This way, you get your red lights as you go.

Comment: My mistake.  The script header would definitely get in the way.